# Facebook API: (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm trying to grant access to business assets to another user's business account.
I'm following this documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/business-to-business#b2b-grant

I'm using the API Graph Explorer to test the requests.
I'm using a test facebook App.

To give access to the fb page, I'm using this request :

> endpoint : page-id/agencies
> type : POST
> body : JSON  :
> {
> "business": "business_account_id",
> "permitted_tasks": "MANAGE"
> }
> and the token I'm using is the page token.

The result is : {
"success": true
}

But when I do the same with the ad account, I get :
"error": {
"message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 3,

The request is :

> **endpoint : act_adAccount-id/agencies
> type : POST
> body : {
> "business": "business_account_id",
> "permitted_tasks": "ANALYZE"
> }**

**and the token is the token generated when the user logged in to my app with these permissions :
email
pages_show_list
ads_management
ads_read
business_management
public_profile**

Could anyone help please ?
Thanks